# PostgreSQL API and QField

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, qfield, qfieldsync

Does anyone know how to create a QField API, because I think it's going to work in my case. What I want to achieve is load a heavy PostgreSQL DB on QField (The project contains a lot of tables about 200 with and without geometries, relationships, and PostGIS extensions, users and functionalities like pgrouting). I am planning to host PostgreSQL on a live server, connect it to QField to collect additional data, and store the collected data in the database.

Comment: have used this postgrest api https://gis-ops.com/postgrest-postgis-api-tutorial-geospatial-api-in-5-minutes/ but not for qfield  - fyi there is a bug {blocker} on the qfield side https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1778